# Relativistic Euler-Lagrange equations for a four-vector (or one-form) field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, notation

I think the best way to ask my question is by considering the maxwell-Lagrangian,

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}).$$

For scalar fields, $\phi_{i}$, we have Euler-Lagrange equations

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi_{i}}  - \partial_{\mu}\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}\phi_{i})}\right)=0.$$

I'm not sure i fully understand what we have for a four vector field. I initially learnt that it would be this

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A^{\mu}}  - \partial_{\nu}\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\nu}A^{\mu})}\right)=0.$$

(obviously you would need to change the indices in $\mathcal{L}$ to something other than $\mu$ and $\nu$ before calculating.)

My question is, does it matter whether we treat $A^{\mu}$ as a vector or can we apply the Euler Lagrange equations to $A_{\mu}$. I.e, is this expression

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A_{\mu}}  - \partial^{\nu}\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\nu}A_{\mu})}\right)=0~?$$

Equally, does it matter whether or the differential $\partial$ and the vector field $A$ are of opposite form, (i.e, if one is one form should the other necessarily be 4-vector). Or can we equally solve

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A_{\mu}}  - \partial_{\nu}\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu})}\right)=0$$

or

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A^{\mu}}  - \partial^{\nu}\left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu})}\right)=0$$

and obtain the same solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. It may matter if the metric components $g_{\nu\lambda}=g_{\nu\lambda}(x)$ [that we use to raise and lower indices with] depend on the spacetime coordinate $x^{\mu}$. This happens e.g. in [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity).
2. In this case, a spacetime derivative $\partial_{\mu}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ and the gauge potential $A_{\mu}$ should have a lower/sub-index by standard convention.
3. In particular, $\partial^{\mu}:=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}$ and $A^{\mu}:=g^{\mu\nu}A_{\nu}$ with an upper/super-index are composite objects by standard convention.
4. Apropos EL equations and differentiation, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321668/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/583744/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

Comment: 1. Interesting, so if we treat the metric, $g_{\mu\nu}$ as a constant between frames, it doesn't matter which one we use? 2. Is there any reason why we conventionally use $\partial_{\mu}A_{\mu}$, other than the fact that it makes the problem much easier to solve?

Comment: 1. Yes, except that we don't 'treat' the metric, which may wrongly suggest that we have options. For fixed coordinate system, the metric components are what they are. 2. Yes, to make $F$ a closed 2-form.

Comment: why would we want it as a two form, we could equally solve the Euler Lagrange equations for the rank (1,1) tensor $\partial_{\mu}A^{\nu}$