# What's the difference between these two lagrangian?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

The lagrangian for scalar field is defined as, $$L=L(\phi,\partial_{\mu}\phi,\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi)\tag{1}$$
$but$ there is also another lagrangian which is defined as, $$L=L(\phi,\nabla_{\mu}\phi,\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\phi)\tag{2}$$ what is the difference between these two lagrangian?

Is first lagrangian defined for flat spacetime and second lagrangian is defined for curved spacetime?

Answer (score 1):

1. The Lagrangian (2) can always be rewritten into the form of the Lagrangian (1) [with possibly a different functional dependence]. The other way requires some geometric input, i.e. a connection $\nabla$.
2. Concerning whether to use partial or covariant derivatives in the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239974/2451) related Phys.SE post.
3. For higher-derivative theories, additional issues arises due to non-commutativity of covariant derivatives.

Answer (score -1):

There might be different habits in different fields of physics (you don't specify which one you're talking about), but for me, coming from quantum field theory, $\partial_\mu$ and $\nabla_\mu$ are exactly the same thing.